# Base constructor vs protected method for constructing derived class

Tags: c#

So, I got a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62287505/should-i-manually-dispose-of-these-streams) that appears to be opinion based. Rather than tackling how and where I need to implement IDisposable, I'd rather question myself how the code is written, is it a good design.

I got a base `Node` class which has a `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` and 2 derived classes `Client` and `Server`. The `Client` only really has to set up his side of the `AnonymousPipes` based upon the `PipeHandles` he gets from the server. The `Server` has to do more since he needs to be able to broadcast his `PipeHandles`.

In reality, the Main application (Server) starts the Child application (Client) with the `PipeHandles` as arguments.

I think my setup is pretty good. I've got an open base `Node` class which can simply Read and Write `Streams`. The derived classes have some more specific info they need to be initialized. Everything looks unit-testable. The "not so nice thing" I did in my opinion is how the `Server` class gets back his `PipeStreams` to get the handles. In order to do this the `Node` has a little bit too much info in order to be a base class (`PipeStream` properties).

Question: Would how I did it be a good way to do it if this was requested to program as a developer at a company? I'm not sure if the `Client` and `Server` constructors are executed well.

```
public class Node
{
    private readonly StreamReader streamIn;
    private readonly StreamWriter streamOut;

    protected Node(PipeStream pipeStreamIn, PipeStream pipeStreamOut)
    {
        PipeStreamIn = pipeStreamIn ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(streamIn));
        PipeStreamOut = pipeStreamOut ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(streamOut));

        streamIn = new StreamReader(pipeStreamIn);
        streamOut = new StreamWriter(pipeStreamOut)
        {
            AutoFlush = true
        };
    }

    protected PipeStream PipeStreamIn { get; }
    protected PipeStream PipeStreamOut { get; }

    public string Read()
    {
        return streamIn.ReadLine();
    }

    public void Write(string line)
    {
        streamOut.WriteLine(line);
    }
}

public class Client : Node
{
    public Client(string pipeInHandleAsString, string pipeOutHandleAsString) : base(new AnonymousPipeClientStream(PipeDirection.In, pipeInHandleAsString), new AnonymousPipeClientStream(PipeDirection.Out, pipeOutHandleAsString)) { }

    public void Sync()
    {
        // Sync code
    }
}

public class Server : Node
{
    public Server() : base(new AnonymousPipeServerStream(PipeDirection.In, HandleInheritability.Inheritable), new AnonymousPipeServerStream(PipeDirection.Out, HandleInheritability.Inheritable))
    {
        ClientPipeInHandleAsString = ((AnonymousPipeServerStream)PipeStreamOut).GetClientHandleAsString();
        ClientPipeOutHandleAsString = ((AnonymousPipeServerStream)PipeStreamIn).GetClientHandleAsString();
    }

    public string ClientPipeInHandleAsString { get; private set; }
    public string ClientPipeOutHandleAsString { get; private set; }

    public void Sync()
    {
        ((AnonymousPipeServerStream)PipeStreamIn).DisposeLocalCopyOfClientHandle();
        ((AnonymousPipeServerStream)PipeStreamOut).DisposeLocalCopyOfClientHandle();

        // Sync code
    }
}
```

I've also got my 1st code design below. There a `protected` `Initialize` method does the things the `Node` `constructor` does in my 2nd design. The `Client` makes his `PipeStreams` and passes them to the `Node`. The `Server` does something similar but needs them as a `field` since he needs to do something with them during the `Sync`.

```
public class Node
{
    private readonly StreamReader streamIn;
    private readonly StreamWriter streamOut;

    protected Initialize(PipeStream pipeStreamIn, PipeStream pipeStreamOut)
    {
        if (streamIn == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(streamIn));
        if (streamOut == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(streamOut));

        streamIn = new StreamReader(pipeStreamIn);
        streamOut = new StreamWriter(pipeStreamOut)
        {
            AutoFlush = true
        };
    }

    public string Read()
    {
        return streamIn.ReadLine();
    }

    public void Write(string line)
    {
        streamOut.WriteLine(line);
    }
}

public class Client : Node
{
    public Client(string pipeInHandleAsString, string pipeOutHandleAsString)
    {
        var streamIn = new AnonymousPipeClientStream(PipeDirection.In, pipeInHandleAsString);
        var StreamOut = new AnonymousPipeClientStream(PipeDirection.Out, pipeOutHandleAsString);

        Initialize(streamIn, StreamOut);
    }

    public void Sync()
    {
        // Sync code
    }
}

public class Server : Node
{
    private readonly AnonymousPipeServerStream streamIn;
    private readonly AnonymousPipeServerStream streamOut;

    public Server()
    {
        streamIn = new AnonymousPipeServerStream(PipeDirection.In, HandleInheritability.Inheritable);
        streamOut = new AnonymousPipeServerStream(PipeDirection.Out, HandleInheritability.Inheritable);

        ClientPipeInHandleAsString = streamOut.GetClientHandleAsString();
        ClientPipeOutHandleAsString = streamIn.GetClientHandleAsString();

        Initialize(streamIn, streamOut);
    }

    public string ClientPipeInHandleAsString { get; private set; }
    public string ClientPipeOutHandleAsString { get; private set; }

    public void Sync()
    {
        streamIn.DisposeLocalCopyOfClientHandle();
        streamOut.DisposeLocalCopyOfClientHandle();

        // Sync code
    }
}
```

Secondly, I think how and where to implement IDisposable is better fit for a separate question but I think I first need to decide which of the 2 above approaches the industry would rather have.

---

**Update 1**

So I've taken Kain0_0's comments into account and this is what I assume might be better. `Node` is renamed to `Peer` and `Client` and `Server` to `ClientPeer` and `ServerPeer`. Their backbone is the same, just how they set up the communication between the 2 is different. I wouldn't know how to enable both to start and listen to init communicaitons.

```
public class Peer
{
    private readonly StreamReader streamIn;
    private readonly StreamWriter streamOut;

    protected Node(PipeStream pipeStreamIn, PipeStream pipeStreamOut)
    {
        if (pipeStreamIn == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(streamIn));
        if (pipeStreamIn.CanRead) throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(streamIn)} does not support reading.");
        if (pipeStreamOut == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(streamOut));
        if (pipeStreamOut.CanWrite) throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(streamOut)} does not support writing.");

        streamIn = new StreamReader(pipeStreamIn);
        streamOut = new StreamWriter(pipeStreamOut)
        {
            AutoFlush = true
        };
    }

    public string Read()
    {
        return streamIn.ReadLine();
    }

    public void Write(string line)
    {
        streamOut.WriteLine(line);
    }
}

public class ClientPeer
{
    private readonly Peer peer;

    public ClientPeer(string pipeInHandleAsString, string pipeOutHandleAsString)
    {
        var pipeStreamIn = new AnonymousPipeClientStream(PipeDirection.In, pipeInHandleAsString);
        var pipeStreamOut = new AnonymousPipeClientStream(PipeDirection.Out, pipeOutHandleAsString);

        peer = new Peer(pipeStreamIn, pipeStreamOut);
    }

    public int MessagesSent => peer.MessagesSent;
    public int MessagesReceived => peer.MessagesReceived;

    public void Sync()
    {
        while (Read().Function != function) { }
        Write(new Message(Function.Sync, "From Client"));
    }

    public IMessage Read()
    {
        return peer.Read();
    }

    public string Write(IMessage message)
    {
        return peer.Write(message);
    }    
}

public class ServerPeer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly AnonymousPipeServerStream pipeStreamIn;
    private readonly AnonymousPipeServerStream pipeStreamOut;
    private readonly Peer peer;

    public ServerPeer()
    {
        pipeStreamIn = new AnonymousPipeServerStream(PipeDirection.In, HandleInheritability.Inheritable);
        pipeStreamOut = new AnonymousPipeServerStream(PipeDirection.Out, HandleInheritability.Inheritable);
        ClientPipeInHandleAsString = pipeStreamOut.GetClientHandleAsString();
        ClientPipeOutHandleAsString = pipeStreamIn.GetClientHandleAsString();

        peer = new Peer(pipeStreamIn, pipeStreamOut);
    }

    public string ClientPipeInHandleAsString { get; }
    public string ClientPipeOutHandleAsString { get; }
    public int MessagesSent => peer.MessagesSent;
    public int MessagesReceived => peer.MessagesReceived;

    public void Sync()
    {
        pipeStreamIn.DisposeLocalCopyOfClientHandle();
        pipeStreamOut.DisposeLocalCopyOfClientHandle();

        Write(new Message(Function.Sync, "From Server"));
        while (Read().Function != function) { }
    }

    public IMessage Read()
    {
        return peer.Read();
    }

    public string Write(IMessage message)
    {
        return peer.Write(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason to treat `Client` and `Server` identically anywhere?

Comment: @Kain0_0, how do you mean?

Comment: Is there a function, an array, or variable that holds `Node` objects, and only interacts with them through the `Node` interface? Because if there isn't then I would not have `Client` and `Server` share such a base class.

Comment: @Kain0_0, no. The `Node` is simply there to have shared methods for `Client` and `Server`. If you wouldn't share a base class in that case, wouldn't I go against the DRY principle of having identical `Read` and `Write` methods in both `Client` and `Server`?

Comment: I would call this an overzealous application of DRY. You are sacrificing meaning to follow a rule. In which way would a `Read` from a `Server`, and a `Read` from the `Client` be anyway identical? They have different meanings, which will force them to change differently, even if they currently contain identical implementations. Unless they are identical, and are in fact `Peers`, and then this collapses to a single class anyway. A good rule of thumb for using DRY is to count 3 to 5 repetitions before refactoring. Also it is better to use composition over inheritance for shared implementations.

Comment: @Kain0_0, I've updated the question based on your comments. I still have a base `Peer` with common code but it's used as a composite instead of using inheritance. Therefore `Peer` is a clean base class with the `ClientPeer` and `ServerPeer` adding another layer on top of it to handle specific things.

Comment: Not what I meant. You just changed their names. If they are indeed peers then there is a single class `Peer`, which has the ability to both initiate a connection, say `void connect_to(Peer)` and also the ability to accept connections such as `void accept(...streams...)`. The flow would be create two `Peers a, b;`. Then call `a.connect_to(b)` in which `a` creates the channels and pass them on by `b.accept(...)`.

Comment: @Kain0_0, well, that's kind of the problem. `a` and `b` are in different applications. Application 1 creates the channels (`AnonymousPipeServerStream`s). Application 2 is started by 1 with arguments. These arguments are the stream handles where Application 2 creates `AnonymousPipeClientStream`s from. Nevertheless, an approuch like you suggest might be possible.